# htaccess misdirection. It repeats the file name

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I get languages via subdomain with httaccess. So far, there is no problem. But when I enter the en.example.com url, I have problems with the files.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.site/public/$1 [N,R=301,L]
```

I am trying to redirect the files in this way. This time, the result is as follows.

```
https://www.example.com/public/images/logo.png/logo.png
```

This is my htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:LANGUAGE} ^$
    RewriteRule (.*) - [QSA,E=LANGUAGE:en]
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?language=%{ENV:LANGUAGE} [QSA]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/public/$1 [N,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    # Prevent directory listings
    Options All -Indexes
    Options +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just a remark about a side issue I see here: if you operate your application from such "subdmains" (actually they are host names), then you certainly do _not_ want to externally redirect requests to icons and stuff!

Comment: What on earth is that line meant to do: ``RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]``?

Comment: @arkascha laravelin exists in itself.

Comment: @Smokie Where did the directive originate that arkascha highlights? Are you suggesting it's part of an official distribution?! Where exactly is this `.htaccess` file located on the filesystem? Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "laravelin exists in itself.", sorry.